# How to turn a salty water into normal, drinkable water?

Tags: unturned

I made a 'maple bottle' in *Unturned*, so that I have something to drink when I'm traveling. I filled my bottle at the ocean and found that it says that the water is salty. It gives you +10 sickness/ radiation when you drink it.

Is there a way to purify the salty water, so that it just restores your thirst and not have any negative effect?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your best bet is to obtain clean water from rain barrels, wells, water towers, or fishing, as no water-distilling mechanics are implemented.

Sources:
[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/unturned/comments/4np7e2/drinking_from_sea_lake_gives_you_radiation_toxic/)
[This Steam thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/304930/discussions/0/355043117502315974/)

Comment: I think water from wells are not clean if I remember correctly, but I'll check that out, to see if wells contain clean water or not. For now I'll not remove wells from the answer, but if it's not clean then I'll remove it. Also I'll accept this answer after I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [Purification Tablets](https://unturned.fandom.com/wiki/Purification_Tablets):

> I figured out yesterday that in the "Repair" Tab of crafting, you can combine Purification Tablets with the Canteen (If it has dirty or salty water in it) To get clean water.

Source: [Kirby1077 @ r/Unturned (Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/unturned/comments/4qtt64/comment/dai6iue/).

Answer (score -1):

I usually use water purification tablets for dirty water.

Answer (score -1):

Make a base and stick some rain barrels on the roof. The water is completely clean and all you have to do is hope for rain.

Another effective way of getting water is by putting generators by vending machines, which are found in some shops etc.
This allows infinite free drinks, although it only lets you take a drink from a vending machine every once in a while.

To answer your question, I don't think there is a way to make dirty water into clean, drinking water